# How can I let user go back to main question after they ask the bot question and got answer?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Let's say this user needs to answer A - B - C - D - E sth like this in the pre-interview setting for a job. Let's say while getting question C, this user wants to ask some questions like salary or sth, then this person got the answer for the questions. 
After this person got the answer if the user says "go back" or "back," I want the user to get the question C again. So currently, because of the context piled up, if that user remembers the question and answer correctly like "yes", it smoothly goes to D question. But people can forget. Also, if it's 'required' like number or something I can just put prompt and put the question again, but in case of simple question like yes or no, i don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is **follow-up intents**. They allow you to perform specific actions when a user says yes or no. Follow the links below to know how to build follow-up intents to suit your application needs.

Official Dialogflow Guide - https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/follow-up-intents

Medium Article with Example - https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/mastering-follow-up-intents-with-dialogflow-851b75b83f5a